# How to get <span> text in class with same name in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

Hello everyone, New Python Learner Here Needs Help on BeautifulSoup

I want to print "Resale" text from "li","class":"keypoint" from the snippet shown in above link and print none where it is not there. I am able to extract old and Bathrooms using the code below in a for loop in python

```
try:
    print("Age :", item.find("li", {'class': "keypoint", "title": "old"}).text)
except:
    print("Age :", "Not Mentioned")
try:
    print("Bathrooms :", item.find("li", {'class': "keypoint", "title": "Bathrooms"}).text)
except:
    print("Bathrooms :", "Not Mentioned")
```

Can someone please tell me how do I get "Resale" text from span?

Comment: @Wondercricket Thank you that worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample HTML, this should do the trick:

```
item.find("li", {'class': 'keypoint', 'title': False})
```

By doing `{'title': False}`, this searches for any tag where the attribute is not present. Since the `li`s for Age and Bathroom have a `title`, these are being excluded

Comment: Thank you that worked for me.

Comment: First one did the trick while in second one it is printing values of different attributes.

Comment: @moon Glad I could help! I went ahead and removed the second one. I added that as an alternative based on your sample HTML, but it would appear it wouldn't be the case